# flutter gridview.count size issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing an issue with the size of the gridview.count. When I give size to gridview.count, the content I added below grid view is not displaying and gridview is also not shows properly, But if I don't give height to gridview.count, it gives "RenderBox laid out" error. Now how can I solve this issue.

Below is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pizzapizza/screens/customGridView.dart';

class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  const Menu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Menu> createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  int _crossAxisCount = 3;
  Color gridactivecountcolor = Color(0xff808080);
  Color gridinactivecountcolor = Color(0xffEEEEEE);
  Color grid2color = Color(0xffEEEEEE);
  Color grid3color = Color(0xff808080);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 1,
                  color: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 10, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/back-arrow.png",
                      height: 24,
                      width: 24,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Text("Back",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Gilroy",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Color(0xff808080),
                            fontSize: 16)),
                    Spacer(),
                    CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 22,
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF6A00),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 20,
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
                          child: Image.asset("assets/images/reserve.png",
                              width: 24, height: 24),
                        )),
                    SizedBox(width: 12),
                    Text("Menu",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Gilroy",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Color(0xff111111),
                            fontSize: 16)),
                    Spacer(),
                    SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1)
                  ]),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 1,
                  color: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          grid2color = gridactivecountcolor;
                          grid3color = gridinactivecountcolor;
                          _crossAxisCount = 2;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: grid2color),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                          width: 36,
                          height: 36,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            child: Image.asset("assets/images/grid-2.png",
                                width: 24, height: 24),
                          )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          grid3color = gridactivecountcolor;
                          grid2color = gridinactivecountcolor;
                          _crossAxisCount = 3;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: grid3color),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                          width: 36,
                          height: 36,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            child: Image.asset("assets/images/grid-3.png",
                                width: 24, height: 24),
                          )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10)
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 600,
                  child: customGridView(
                    crossAxiscount: _crossAxisCount,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  "Test",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Gilroy",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Color(0xff808080),
                      fontSize: 50),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the code of customGridView Class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class customGridView extends StatefulWidget {
  customGridView({Key? key, required this.crossAxiscount}) : super(key: key);
  int crossAxiscount;

  @override
  _customGridViewState createState() => _customGridViewState();
}

class _customGridViewState extends State<customGridView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: widget.crossAxiscount,
      childAspectRatio: 0.6,
      children: [
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg2.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg3.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg4.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg5.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg2.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg3.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg4.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
        gridContainer(imgpath: "assets/images/bg5.png", title: "Title", views: "365"),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class gridContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  gridContainer({Key? key, required this.title, required this.imgpath, required this.views}) : super(key: key);
  String imgpath;
  String title;
  String views;

  @override
  State<gridContainer> createState() => _gridContainerState();
}

class _gridContainerState extends State<gridContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
      child: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 150,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              widget.imgpath,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 40,
                child:
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Image.asset("assets/images/eye.png", width: 24, height: 24,),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Text(
                      widget.views,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Gilroy",
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 14,
                left: 10,
                child: Text(widget.title, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Gilroy", fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Color(0xffffffff), fontSize: 18)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For full body scrolling, I will suggest using `CustomScrolView` on this case.

For this current snippet, you can use `shrinkWrap: true` on gridView
and remove `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` from ListView.

You can also set `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` on gridView but it won't be needed while `shrinkWrap:true` ig.

---

Only Gridview scrollable.

Use `Expanded` to get available space:

```dart
Expanded( 
  child: customGridView(
  crossAxiscount: _crossAxisCount,
    ),
 ),
```

And you can remove `ListView` while it is having `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

Comment: Already tried and it doesn't work, It gives the following error "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded."

Comment: have you remove the ListView? or do you want full body scrollable ?

Comment: I want to scroll the full body, that is why I used the listview